# Test lightning-emp-api

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-jest, empapi

Can we simulate an event subscription in LWC unit test? I have a lightning web component using `lighting/empApi` like,

```
export default class ExampleComponent extends LightningElement {
    connectedCallback() {
        const onMessageCallback = (response) => {
            if (this.isSomething) { //Not a public (@api) parameter
                //Do something
            }
        };

        subscribe('/event/ExamplePlatformEvent__e', -1, onMessageCallback).then((response) => {
            console.log('Successfully subscribed to : ', JSON.stringify(response.channel));
        });
    }
}
```

Now, the latest `sfdx-lwc-jest` has a stub of `lightning/empApi` and I can instantiate the above component with a mock implementation in a test.

```
describe('c-example-component', () => {
    it('test', () => {
        const mockResponse = {
            "id": "_1583742038741_4782",
            "channel": "/event/ExamplePlatformEvent__e",
            "replayId": -1
        }
        const mockEvent = {
            "data": {
                "schema": "a9SbAGsZvysbJq_U77Mv6Q",
                "payload": {
                    "CreatedById": "00556000004PKXTAA4",
                    "CreatedDate": "2020-03-09T14:05:35Z",
                    "SomethingField__c": "ABCDEFG"
                },
                "event": {
                    "replayId": 123
                }
            },
            "channel": "/event/ExamplePlatformEvent__e"
        }

        subscribe.mockImplementation((channel, replayId, onMessageCallback) => {
            onMessageCallback(mockEvent);
            return Promise.resolve(mockResponse);
        });

        const element = createElement('c-example-component', {
                is: ExampleComponent
            });
        document.body.appendChild(element);

        expect(subscribe.mock.calls[0][0]).toBe('/event/ExamplePlatformEvent__e');
        expect(subscribe.mock.calls[0][1]).toBe(-1);
    });
});
```

In the above test, mock `subscribe()` is called one time during `connectedCallback()`. But **how to call** `onMessageCallback` **again after component is rendered?** The parameter `isSomething` is false for the first time and it will be true by a user operation after component is rendered. So, inside the if clause in onMessageCallback cannot be covered in the current test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Too bad this question didn't get an answer earlier.  I was able to make this work by using the Module Imports concept under [Jest Test Patterns](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.unit_testing_using_jest_patterns) in the LWC Docs.  Credit also goes to [this StackExchange answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/310310/53350) for clarifying how to flush all promises in Node.

Create the following files:

**force-app\test\jest-mocks\lightning\empApi.js** (this is your custom `lightning/empApi` stub)

```js
// An object to store callbacks
const _channels = {};

// On subscribe, store the callback function and resolve the promise
export const subscribe = jest.fn((channel, replayId, onMessageCallback) => {
    _channels[channel] = { onMessageCallback };
    Promise.resolve({
        id: "_" + Date.now(),
        channel: channel,
        replayId: replayId
    });
});

// I'm using isEmpEnabled in my component, so I have it set to return true
export const isEmpEnabled = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(true);

// A Jest-specific function for "publishing" your Platform Event
export const jestMockPublish = jest.fn((channel, message) => {
    if (
        _channels[channel] &&
        _channels[channel].onMessageCallback instanceof Function
    ) {
        _channels[channel].onMessageCallback(message);
    }
    Promise.resolve(true);
});

// I just copied these from the standard lightning/empApi stub
export const unsubscribe = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({});
export const onError = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(jest.fn());
export const setDebugFlag = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue();
```

**jest.config.js** (this overrides the stub from `sfdx-lwc-jest` and goes at the root of your project)

```js
const { jestConfig } = require("@salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest/config");
module.exports = {
    ...jestConfig,
    moduleNameMapper: {
        "^lightning/empApi$":
            "<rootDir>/force-app/test/jest-mocks/lightning/empApi"
    }
};
```

Now, if your component looks like this...

**force-app\main\default\lwc\myComponent\myComponent.js**

```js
import { LightningElement, api, track } from "lwc";
import {
    subscribe,
    unsubscribe,
    onError,
    isEmpEnabled
} from "lightning/empApi";

export default class MyComponent extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    @track events = [];
    channelName = "/event/My_Platform_Event__e";
    subscription = {};

    async connectedCallback() {
        const empEnabled = await isEmpEnabled();
        if (empEnabled) {
            this.subscription = await subscribe(this.channelName, -2, event => {
                // Your event processing logic here
                console.log(event.data.payload);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

...you can test it like this...

```js
import { createElement } from "lwc";
import myComponent from "c/myComponent";
import { jestMockPublish } from "lightning/empApi";
// eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
const flushPromises = () => new Promise(setImmediate);

describe("myComponent tests", () => {
    afterEach(() => {
        while (document.body.firstChild) {
            document.body.removeChild(document.body.firstChild);
        }
    });

    // NOTE -- THIS IS ASYNC
    it("does what I expect", async () => {
        const element = createElement("my-component", {
            is: myComponent
        });
        element.recordId = "OPP001";
        // Add the component to the DOM
        document.body.appendChild(element);

        // Make sure async subscribe call in connectedCallback completes
        await flushPromises();

        // connectedCallback is now complete, but no Platform Events have 
        // been published yet.  Make assertions here about the state of your 
        // component prior to receiving the Platform Events.

        // Mock-publish a Platform Event and await the promise
        await jestMockPublish("/event/My_Platform_Event__e", {
            data: {
                payload: {
                    Opportunity__c: "OPP001",
                    My_Custom_Field__c: 123
                }
            }
        });
        // Now any DOM updates that depend on the Platform Event should 
        // have rendered; assert about them here
    });
});
```