# In an unit test for an LWC, how can I prove an async chain is setting a value in a lightning-formatted-number?

Tags: unit-test, lightning-web-components, asynchronous, lwc-jest, wait-element

I am trying to prove that the price is being set on the component.

I have the following HTML:

```html
<template>
    <h1>Current price of a bitcoin in Euro</h1>
    <lightning-formatted-number 
        currency-code="EUR"
        format-style="currency"
        value={euroPrice}>
    </lightning-formatted-number>
</template>
```

And the following JavaScript:

```js
import {LightningElement, api, track} from 'lwc';

const bitcoinPriceProvider = 'https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/spot?currency=EUR';
export default class BitcoinEuroPrice extends LightningElement {
    @api
    refreshRateInSeconds;

    @track
    euroPrice;

    connectedCallback() {
        this.fetchPrice();
        setInterval(this.fetchPrice, this.refreshRateInSeconds * 1000);
    }

    fetchPrice() {
        fetch(bitcoinPriceProvider)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(json => {
                this.euroPrice = json.data.amount;
                console.log('######## this.euroPrice: ', this.euroPrice);
            });
    }
}
```

This is my test:

```js
import {createElement} from 'lwc';
import BitcoinEuroPrice from 'c/bitcoinEuroPrice';

describe('c-bitcoinEuroPrice', () => {
    afterEach(() => {
        while (document.body.firstChild) {
            document.body.removeChild(document.body.firstChild);
        }
    });

    it('fetches price', () => {
        // Arrange
        const testAmount = '8448.947391885';
        const mockApiResponse = {
            'data': {
                'base': 'BTC',
                'currency': 'EUR',
                'amount': testAmount
            }
        };
        fetch = global.fetch = mockFetch(mockApiResponse);

        // Act
        const priceUnderTest = createElement('c-bitcoinEuroPrice', {
            is: BitcoinEuroPrice
        });
        document.body.appendChild(priceUnderTest);

        // Assert
        expect(global.fetch).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
        expect(global.fetch).toHaveBeenCalledWith('https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/spot?currency=EUR');

        const displayPrice = priceUnderTest.shadowRoot.querySelector('lightning-formatted-number');
        console.log('##### priceUnderTest', priceUnderTest);
        console.log('##### displayPrice', displayPrice);
        expect(displayPrice.value).toEqual(testAmount);
    });

    function mockFetch(mockApiResponse) {
        return jest
            .fn()
            .mockImplementationOnce(() =>
                Promise.resolve({
                    ok: true,
                    json: () => Promise.resolve(mockApiResponse),
                    jsonResponse: mockApiResponse
                })
            );
    }
});
```

This fails with:

```bash
 expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality
 
     Expected: "8448.947391885"
     Received: undefined
 
       34 |         console.log('##### priceUnderTest', priceUnderTest);
       35 |         console.log('##### displayPrice', displayPrice);
     > 36 |         expect(displayPrice.value).toEqual(testAmount);
          |         ^
       37 |     });
       38 |
```

but further down the log I see:

```bash
   console.log
 force-app/main/default/lwc/bitcoinEuroPrice/bitcoinEuroPrice.js:21
     ######## this.euroPrice:  8448.947391885
```

My hypothesis is that the test is not waiting for the asynchronous chain to complete before checking the value.

How can I make it wait?
Or is there some other way I should check the value?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Figured out a way to flush the promises by applying answer from
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44741102/how-to-make-jest-wait-for-all-asynchronous-code-to-finish-execution-before-expec

essentially just needed to:

1. Add this function/constant:

```
const flushPromises = () => new Promise(setImmediate);
```

2. Make the test async:

```
it('fetches price', async () => {
```

3. Wait for the flush:

```
        document.body.appendChild(priceUnderTest);
        await flushPromises();
```

Comment: `setImmediate` no longer works with the version of jsdom lwc uses

Comment: Just hit the same issue after updating lwc-jest. @TemporaryFix have you found alternative?

Comment: `import 'setImmediate'` seemingly solved it

Comment: Or better yet put  "import { setImmediate } from 'timers';"   at the top of your test.js program.   If that errors out then install the node timer module.

Comment: Just wanted to come back and say there's an updated way to do this with `process.nextTick`. See more [here](https://nodejs.dev/learn/understanding-process-nexttick) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51045733/3135974)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into an issue with testing async functionality. I attempted to use the `flushPromises` utility method mentioned in the other answer, and while that works for [Promises that have resolved and their callbacks were added to the task queue](https://youtu.be/8aGhZQkoFbQ?t=711) it does not work for Promises that have not resolved.

Instead of waiting for an unsure amount of time with `setTimeout` to make sure your async functionality has finished before running your assertions, I built a simple utility called [`waitFor`](https://gist.github.com/joeythomaschaske/6d93e984142299e6a01b277b0dc652da)

This is a concept taken from reactjs's [testing library](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async/#waitfor). Their [implementation](https://github.com/testing-library/dom-testing-library/blob/1fc17bec5d28e5b58fcdd325d6d2caaff02dfb47/src/wait-for.js) is a lot more complex than my simple utility function, but it gets the job done.

In case the gist link ever becomes broken this is the utility, add it to your `jest.setup.js` file.

```js
global.waitFor = (expectationFunction) => {
    const MAX_WAIT = 4000;
    const POLL_INTERVAL = 100;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const startTime = Date.now();
        let error;
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            try {
                if (Date.now() - startTime < MAX_WAIT) {
                    expectationFunction();
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    resolve();
                } else {
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    reject(error);
                }
            } catch (e) {
                error = e.matcherResult;
            }
        }, POLL_INTERVAL);
    });
};

// in your test method call waitFor like this
const button = element.shadowRoot.querySelector('button');
button.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('click')); // calls an async handler

await waitFor(() => { expect(createUserKey.mock.calls.length).toBe(1) });
```

Make sure your [linter is aware](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/language-options#specifying-globals) this is a global function by adding this to your `.eslintrc.json` file:

```json
"globals": {
  "waitFor": true,
},
```