# Sharing mocks in LWC tests

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am trying to build some shared mocks for common utilities such as the lightning platform resource loader, which I mocked like so:

```
jest.mock(
    'lightning/platformResourceLoader',
    () => {
        return {
            loadScript() {
                return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    resolve();
                });
            }
        };
    },
    { virtual: true }

);
```

This is included in my tests, and I know jest support module mocking so I was wondering if the an alternative would be to place under my sfdx-project root a `lightning/platformResourceLoader/__mocks__/platformResourceLoader.json` file. Is this the right approach to sharing mocks in lwc testing?

Answer (score 2):

See the Module Imports section under [Jest Test Patterns](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.unit_testing_using_jest_patterns) in the LWC Docs.

It's going to be something like this...

Create a custom `lightning-platform-resource-loader` stub:

**force-app\test\jest-mocks\lightning\platformResourceLoader.js**

```js
export const loadScript = jest.fn(() => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve();
    });
});
```

Now customize your Jest configuration:

**jest.config.js** (this overrides the stub from sfdx-lwc-jest and goes at the root of your project)

```js
const { jestConfig } = require("@salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest/config");
module.exports = {
    ...jestConfig,
    moduleNameMapper: {
        "^lightning/platformResourceLoader$":
            "<rootDir>/force-app/test/jest-mocks/lightning/platformResourceLoader"
    }
};
```

The stub itself may require tweaking to get it to return exactly the right thing. See my answer [on this thread](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/297563) for a working example where I globally mocked another `lightning` namespace API, `lightning/empApi`.

Comment: So useful, brilliant. Can I use this pattern to mock also the global.window ?

Comment: Haven't tried it, seems worth an attempt.  Check this if you haven't already: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41885841

Comment: also, what about generic test utils? how should they be shared?

Comment: I haven't crossed that bridge yet either, and you can probably come to your own conclusion about the proper SFDX directory location for test utils.  One option would be to create an LWC bundle with test helpers and use it as described here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.js_share_code.  Or you could put it pretty much anywhere and use a relative import statement to get it.  You will also want to read this thread if you haven't yet: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50411719

Comment: As an example, you can import a helper from another LWC bundle like this: `import { helper } from "../../anotherLwc/__tests__/testHelper.js";`

Comment: If this answer helped you, please mark it "accepted" -- thanks!